# extract text from a webpage file using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, html, text-extraction

How to extract text from a specific area of a webpage (in Arabic not English) given the url using C/C++?

For example: given the url of [this wikipedia article](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B3%D9%8A_%D8%A5%D9%86_%D8%A5%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9) I want to extract the body of the article (highlighted in the image below) and throw away the other parts of the webpage like the heading, the menus on the right and on the left, etc. I only need the body to be parsed into a string.

[image: example image]

Comment: You can use [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)!

Comment: Expanding on the "use cURL" comment-and-link: of course no library or tool will work "out of the box". cURL allows easy downloading of your page. Cleaning the HTML of anything you don't need is something you need to write.

Comment: As a note, there is no language called C/C++. Modern C and modern C++ are very different languages and the idiomatic solution for one may not work in the other. Unless you are asking to compare/contrast in some way, tag only the language you are actually using/compiling.

Comment: @crashmstr thanks but slash "/" means "or". I meant c or c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the article text  from a Wikipedia page, add [`?action=render`](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B3%D9%8A_%D8%A5%D9%86_%D8%A5%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9?action=render) to your url.

Then use e.g. curl to fetch it. Search the web for curl/c++ tutorials if you don't know how. You are looking for something like this (just to give you an idea):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {

    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode result;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B3%D9%8A_%D8%A5%D9%86_%D8%A5%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9?action=render");

    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in the above program, which variable/object holds the content of the webpage?

Comment: I don't know a lot of C++, but I think you can provide a callbackfunction like this: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, myWriteFunction);`